# Why won't drag and resize work for me in FullCalendar 2.8.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

After upgrading from fullcalendar 2.0.2 to fullcalender 2.8.0, it's generating an event that looks like this:

```
<a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable" etc etc>
  <div class="fc-content">
    <div class="fc-time" data-start="10:30" etc etc></div>
    <div class="fc-title">Foo</div></div>
  <div class="fc-bg"></div>
  <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
</a>
```

It's being generated from a JSON feed that sets `editable`, `startEditable` and `durationEditable` to be true. The global equivalents of these are also true. Given the classes we can see are being set on the `<a>`, I'd say these are being set correctly.

So it should be draggable and resizable.

And when you hover the cursor over the edge, it changes to an arrow to invite you to resize it.

But the events cannot be resized or dragged.

How can I diagnose what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this version support delay touch, are you sure you are checking on web ? or touch device, if touch device then you need to long press.

One more thing noticed: durationEditable to eventDurationEditable

If still not getting, than create pluker so it will be more clear

Cheers!